# Should I minify javascript in userscripts for Greasemonkey or Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, optimization, greasemonkey, minify, userscripts

Is it worthwhile to minify a script that goes into an extension or userscript for Greasemonkey?  I ask because the user will just be downloading it once and running it many times (it's not part of the webpage).  Assume that it's about 50k uncompressed.

Will it save time for the user?  Is it significant or is most of the gain in the download speed?

Answer (score 2):

Minifying javascript is only interesting for increasing the download speed. The execution of the javascript will not be faster.

Comment: What about the parsing of the javascript?  Also no great improvement?

Answer (score 2):

Do not minify your code.  This helps others to understand it -- which is important because many people will not use a script unless they can be reasonably sure that it's not doing bad things.

Also, decent code makes it easier for users to help you debug problems and for other users to modify it to taste (We've all started on the backs of programmers that came before).

As the others stated, any speed/performance gains will be too small to measure.

Comment: I was going to provide a link to the unminified version anyway but I agree that it's annoying to have to switch between versions.

Comment: @Brock Adams Any ideas on how to tune up the performance of my user script since minification of js wont help?

Comment: @Lucky, there's no one answer to that and it depends a lot on what you are doing. Lookup standard JS optimization techniques (not bandwidth techniques).  Two quite-common problems are: length check inside a for loop, and using anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

It will reduce the download time, but most likely only slightly, and the user won't notice it. A webpage usually minifies js to save bandwidth and loading times, but in your case none of these are relevant.